# Spark : efficient joins

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose a simple app like that, triggered every day :

```scala
// Read new data
val newDataDf = spark.read.parquet("path/to/newData")
// Read the current Parquet database
val currentDataDf = spark.read.parquet("path/to/currentParquetDatabase")

// Remove from current dataset, every row which has a match in new dataset, in order to drop old data
val result = currentDataDf.join(newDataDf, Seq("id"), "left_anti")

result
     // add the new data to the result
     .unionAll(newDataDf)
     // write the result back to the current Parquet database
     .spark.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("path/to/currentParquetDatabase")
```

Note that :

- goal is just to merge two dataset
- currentDatabase is as large as `2TB`, newData is as small as `20GB`
- structure for new and current perfectly match, so union is possible
- `id` is a high cardinality column

The problem is that every day, a full shuffle seems to be triggered which is very slow.

**Question :** how it is possible to avoid full shuffle on that case ?

I mean, how to store efficiently the `currentParquetDatabase` to avoid full shuffle every day ?

For instance, by isolating in a particular Spark partition all data related to a particular ID, so that it is guarantee to belong to a single and same partition

**About ChatGPT response :**

ChatGPT give the following codes.

A one time app, that is run only once :

```scala
// Read the initial data
val initialDataDf = spark.read.parquet("path/to/initialData")

// Bucketing and Sorting
val bucketedInitialDataDf = initialDataDf
  .repartition($"id") // Ensure data with the same id is in the same partition
  .sortWithinPartitions($"id") // Sort data within each partition by id
  .write
  .bucketBy(100, "id") // Choose an appropriate number of buckets (e.g., 100)
  .sortBy("id")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .parquet("path/to/initialBucketedData")
```

And the recurrent app every day :

```scala
// Read new data
val newDataDf = spark.read.parquet("path/to/newData")

// Read the initial bucketed dataset created in App 1
val bucketedCurrentDataDf = spark.read.parquet("path/to/initialBucketedData")

// Remove from current dataset, every row which has a match in new dataset, in order to drop old data
val result = bucketedCurrentDataDf
  .join(newDataDf, Seq("id"), "left_anti")
  .unionAll(newDataDf)

// Partitioning by date (assuming you have a date column)
result
  .write
  .partitionBy("date_column") // Partition by the date column
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .parquet("path/to/currentParquetDatabase")
```

However, it's unclear if the bucketing optimizing technique persist at each execution of the second app with that code. And the data_column partition by is strange, as I have no date in the dataset

Comment: The key to preventing shuffle/exchange is to ensure that the data that needs to be joined is co-located on the same partition. This can be achieved by using the broadcast hint or by repartitioning your DataFrames using the same partitioner.

Comment: Thank you. Broadcasting is not an option, because the volume for new data may be more or less from a day to an other (so it may not fit in memory). Regarding the repartition solution, if I end up to do a repartition at the beginning of the app on each dataset, shuffle will be triggered each time on the repartition() call, so we just move the problem, isn't it ? May be you could elaborate as an answer ?

Comment: You can take a look to different blogs https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/bucketing-in-spark-878d2e02140f. Although, you problem is trying to reduce shuffle and either at query or write. I would investigate broadcast(trying to cache the intermediate shuffled files) dividing the small dataset, because you have a very big difference between the two dfs. Or filtering as previous step. I think that if you create buckets for the two dfs you should reduce the shuffle, but these problems are difficult.

Comment: Just an idea, join can be done with 'broadcast(newDataDf.select("id"))' instead of all 'newDataDf', only ids can take less memory. PS: I did not check such approach before.

Comment: I will try, thank you. But as said before, ID is a high cardinality column, so I may have scability problem when using the broadcast approach globally